# How to insert JSON array of arrays into PostgreSQL as separate elements

Tags: c#, arrays, json, postgresql

I have JSON array of arrays

```
[[\"97.00000\",\"1.00000000\",1378856831.546,\"s\",\"m\",\"\"],
 [\"96.99000\",\"0.00987833\",1379071035.0723,\"b\",\"m\",\"\"],
 [\"96.30000\",\"0.10384000\",1379085887.0434,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
 [\"96.20000\",\"0.10395000\",1379086063.4595,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
 [\"96.00000\",\"0.79221000\",1379086126.0679,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"]]
```

I want to insert each of the entries into separate columns and rows in PostgreSQL:

```
first(double precision)|sec(double precision)|thr(double precision)|fou(text)|fiv(text)|six(text)
97.00000          | 1.00000000     |1378856831.546 |s       |m     | |
96.99000          | 0.00987833     |1379071035.0723|b       |m     | |
.
.
```

If I do something like:

```
INSERT INTO my_schema.my_table_second 
(first_col, secon_col, third_col, 
first_char_col, secon_char_col, third_char_col) 
VALUES json_array_elements(
    [[\"97.00000\",\"1.00000000\",1378856831.546,\"s\",\"m\",\"\"],
     [\"96.99000\",\"0.00987833\",1379071035.0723,\"b\",\"m\",\"\"],
     [\"96.30000\",\"0.10384000\",1379085887.0434,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
     [\"96.20000\",\"0.10395000\",1379086063.4595,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
     [\"96.00000\",\"0.79221000\",1379086126.0679,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
     [\"231.00000\",\"0.02164502\",1383838824.8187,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
     [\"224.00000\",\"0.84580357\",1383839436.6596,\"b\",\"l\",\"\"]]));
```

I am getting error. Can someone give an example on how to parse this array or there is only option to format the string outside from SQL?

Comment: Post the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of unnecessary characters `\` with the function `replace().` Also, you should use `select`, not `values:`

```
with my_data(data) as (
values
('[[\"97.00000\",\"1.00000000\",1378856831.546,\"s\",\"m\",\"\"],
 [\"96.99000\",\"0.00987833\",1379071035.0723,\"b\",\"m\",\"\"],
 [\"96.30000\",\"0.10384000\",1379085887.0434,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
 [\"96.20000\",\"0.10395000\",1379086063.4595,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"],
 [\"96.00000\",\"0.79221000\",1379086126.0679,\"s\",\"l\",\"\"]]')
)

insert into my_schema.my_table_second (
    first_col, 
    secon_col, 
    third_col,  
    first_char_col, 
    secon_char_col, 
    third_char_col) 
select 
    (arr->>0)::float, 
    (arr->>1)::float, 
    (arr->>2)::float,   
    arr->>3, 
    arr->>4, 
    arr->>5
from my_data
cross join json_array_elements(replace(data, '\', '')::json) arr
```